# Solr facet tag exclude does not work with space

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am using exclude and tag for faceting. Strange this is it works where I don't have space in value.

`http://192.168.2.114:8983/solr/customer/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=(%7B!tag%3DstateName%7DstateName:%22Gujarat%22)&fq=(%7B!tag%3DstateName%7DstateName:%22AndhraPradesh%22)&facet=true&facet.limit=100&facet.mincount=0&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7DcountryName&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7DstateName&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7Dicity&facet=true` - This works

but

`http://192.168.2.114:8983/solr/customer/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=(%7B!tag%3DstateName%7DstateName:%22Gujarat%22)&fq=(%7B!tag%3DstateName%7DstateName:%22Andhra Pradesh%22)&facet=true&facet.limit=100&facet.mincount=0&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7DcountryName&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7DstateName&facet.field=%7B!ex%3DstateName%7Dicity&facet=true` - This does not

The only difference between these two is a **space** in `{!tag=stateName}stateName="Andhra Pradesh"` (`{!tag=stateName}stateName="AndhraPradesh"` - this works).

I don't understand why. I have tried encoding the URL, i.e. put **`+`** or **`%20`** for space, still no luck.

PFA images for the same[image]

Working copy[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the definition of `stateName` field.

`<field name="stateName" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

`<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>`

Comment: Can you post full request producing error in second image? It says "Cannot parse..." seems like you have an unescaped special character in query.
btw %27 is not for space, %20 is.

Comment: This is the full image, I only go this much response.

Comment: And yes, I have tried with %20, it is typo while typing question. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that [local parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Local+Parameters+in+Queries) in query must be at the beginning of the string:

```
{!tag=stateName}(stateName:"Andhra Pradesh")
```

and not

```
({!tag=stateName}stateName:"Andhra Pradesh")
```

You can also avoid parenthesis:

```
{!tag=stateName}stateName:"Andhra Pradesh"
```

Comment: Did not understand the answer, which one of these three will work? Is Parenthesis problem?

Comment: yes, seems that local parameters (all what is between `{!` and `}`) should stay outside parenthesis